# An inequality between functions

Tags: functions, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $X$ be a finite set and $f_1,\cdots f_k$ are disjointly supported function from $X$ to $\mathfrak{R}$, meaning that $\forall x \in X$ and $i \neq j$ both $f_i(x)$ and $f_j(x)$ can not be non zero simultaneously. In other words $f_i(x)f_j(x)=0 \forall x \in X , i\neq j$.

Show that $(f(x)-f(y))^2 \leq 2 \sum_{i=1}^k(f_i(x)-f_i(y))^2, \forall x,y\in X$, where $f=\sum_{i}f_i$.

**My approach**

$(f(x)-f(y))^2 = (\sum_i f_i(x) - \sum_i f_i(y))^2$

$=(\sum_if_i(x))^2 + (\sum_if_i(y))^2 - 2\sum_if_i(x)\sum_if(y)$

$=\sum_if_i(x)^2 + \sum_if_i(y)^2 -2\sum_if_i(x)f_i(y) - 2\sum_{i\neq j} f_i(x)f_j(y)$

$=\sum_i(f_i(x)-f_i(y))^2 - 2\sum_{i\neq j} f_i(x)f_j(y)$

In the above calculation of $(\sum_if_i(x))^2$, we have used the disjointedness property.
Now I am kind of stuck.
Can someone please figure it out? Thank you.

The above question is from [here](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~shayan/thesis.pdf) [page 160].

Comment: I have fixed the first inequality, please check if that is correct now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would proceed as follows: If
$$
f(x) = f_n(x) \,,\quad f(y) = f_n(x)
$$
for some index $n$ then
$$
 \bigl(f(x) - f(y)\bigr)^2 = \bigl(f_n(x) - f_n(y)\bigr)^2 \le 2 \sum_{i=1}^k \bigl(f_i(x)-f_i(y) \bigr)^2 \, .
$$
Otherwise there are indices $m \ne n$ such that
$$
 f(x) = f_m(x) \, , \quad f(y) = f_n(y) \, , \\
 f_n(x) = 0 \, , \quad f_m(y) = 0 \, .
$$
Then
$$
\bigl(f(x) - f(y) \bigr)^2 = \bigl(f_m(x) - f_n(y) \bigr)^2 \\
\sum_{i=1}^k \bigl(f_i(x)-f_i(y) \bigr)^2 =  f_m(x)^2 + f_n(y)^2
 $$
and the inequality reduces to
$$
\bigl(f_m(x) - f_n(y) \bigr)^2 \le 2 \bigl( f_m(x)^2 + f_n(y)^2 \bigr)
$$
which is easily verified.

Comment: $f$ is the sum of $f_i$s. Can you please explain why are you assuming $f$ to be equal to a single $f_i$? Any why is $\sum_{i=1}^k \bigl(f_i(x)-f_i(y) \bigr)^2 =  f_m(x)^2 + f_n(y)^2$ true?

Comment: @SudiptaRoy: $f(x)$ is always equal to some $f_i(x)$ because of the disjointness property. – In the second case, $f_i(x) \ne 0$ only for $i = m$, and $f_j(y) \ne 0$ only for $i=n$.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Marking as accepted.